# p2pool not showing hashrate

Tags: p2pool, guiminer

so i wanted to test these for somewhat educational purposes and maybe make some profit along (highly unlikely), I have downloaded bitcoin core, and synced it completly, started a local p2pool pool, and connected a bunch of PC and macs to it through GUIminer, the strange thing is, CPU even with much lower Hash rate, find more shares, also Intel graphics had more shares and accepted shares, with only about 3.9 MH/s, and p2pool local hashrate is always 0 H/s even after running the miners for 5-6 hours, why is that? is there someting wrong with GUIminer, I have tested CGminer as well, waited for 10 minutes but still no change on p2pool local hashrate, all connect through 127.0.0.1:9332, all related ports are opened.
p2pool version is 14.0 and I have followed the instructions  here http://p2pool.in